# Use radio button instead of drop down/OptionsCollection

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, netbeans-7

I need to modify this code so that "Male" and "Female" are displayed and selected for as radio buttons instead of using an optionscollection/drop down?

Here is the code that is being used currently

```
<html:select property="gender">
    <html:optionsCollection property="genderList" label="label" value="value"/>
</html:select>
```

In another file, there is this code

```
public void reset(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
    setGender(null);
    setGenderList(null);

    ArrayList gList = new ArrayList();
    gList.add(new LabelValueBean("Male", "Male"));
    gList.add(new LabelValueBean("Female", "Female"));
    setGenderList(gList);
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}


public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}


public ArrayList getGenderList() {
    return genderList;
}


public void setGenderList(ArrayList genderList) {
    this.genderList = genderList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Struts. Hence the solution would be,

```
<html:radio property="gender" value="Male">
<html:radio property="gender" value="Female">
```

You cannot use collections property for radio button.  There is no sense though on using collection for radio button. You have to create the radio button tags as much as you needed and while creating you have to specify the value for each radio button.

Comment: How do you do it using the ArrayList? I ask because this is a simple example.

Comment: On reset you are setting the list to default values. How are you using the list? How it is been mapped to drop down in your current code?

Comment: <html:select property="gender">
        <html:optionsCollection property="genderList" label="label"  value="value"/>
    </html:select>

Comment: @user1361488 why do you need collection for radio button? The idea behind having collection for drop down is if the drop down is editable then to add the values to the existing drop down, collections are used and to reset to initial values collections are used. What was the idea of using collections in your case?

Comment: thats whats being used currently, I want to replace it with code for radio buttons

Comment: My thought is there is no need for arraylist when using radio buttons!! Because when you create radio button, you have to specify value for it.